# can't get form collections to work in symfony 2.6

Tags: php, forms, symfony, exception, collections

i am fairly new to symfony and i can't get the form collection type to work in my project, what i am try to do is similair this project https://github.com/khepin/ProductBundle ,so basically every product can have one or more tags,so here is the code :
Product.php

```
/**
* Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Product
{
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
* @var type 
*/
private $tags;
 /**
 * Add tags
 *
 * @param Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
 */
public function addTags(\Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tags;
    $tags->setProduct($this);
}
}
```

Tag.php

```
    /**
* Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Tag
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Tag
{
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="tags")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* @var type 
*/
private $product;
}
```

ProductType.php

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
                ->add('tags', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new TagType(), 
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    ))
        ;

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'khepin_productbundle_producttype';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options){
        return array('data_class' => 'Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Product');
    }

}
```

the twig template for Product/new.html.twig  :

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Product creation</h1>

<form action="{{ path('product_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </p>
</form>

<ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('product') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="jslink">
            Add a tag
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% include "KhepinProductBundle:Product:js.html.twig" %}
{% endblock %}
```

when the ProductController is like this

```
public function newAction()
{
    $product = new Product();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);

    return array(
        'product' => $product,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

the form renders with no tag fields, but when i add a tag to the product :

```
 public function newAction()
{
    $product= new Product();
    $product->addTags(new Tag());
    $form   = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);

    return array(
        'product' => $product,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

it throws this exeption:

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Tag. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Tag" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Tag to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.
```

any idea on what i am doing wrong, i spent alot of time searching but i found nothing

Comment: Add to your ProductType() use App/Bundle/TagType()

Comment: ProductType and TagType are in the same namespace so no need to do that

Comment: You don't have to do this line $product->getTags()->add(new Tag()); your problem most likely in your formtype i think , how does it look like? and how is your twig? the tag form doesn't show is the problem, the error you have is related to how you add the new tag in your newAction, you must implement addTags function to Product entity normally it can be generated automatically if you have Many Tags To One Product relation

Comment: actualy before using the $product->getTags()->add(new Tag()), i was using the already implemented addTags() but i got the same exception,i have added the twig template code ,as well as the implementation of addtags()

Comment: [Collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) field type won't display any fields in twig unless any fields are available, you have to add tag fields with the help of Javascript. Check the given link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at [this](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=83909&p=185486&hilit=collection+The+form%27s+view+data+is+expected#p185486)
i realized i was missing this two methods

on ProductType.php

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Product',
    ));
}
```

and on TagType.php

```
 public function setDefaultOptions (OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Khepin\ProductBundle\Entity\Tag',
    ));
}
```

so basically i was calling getDefaultOptions() when i should've called setDefaultOptions()